# Office365 mailbox auditing by default

Tags: exchange, office365

Microsoft have recently enabled mailbox auditing by default.

Up until now i have custom actions set on my org mailboxes, and this was set each day on a recurring schedule.

Now with auditing by default enabled i have a bunch of questions;

- Is it safe to Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $false on all mailboxes
  (because it will instead be enabled at the tenant level?
- Is it safe to Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner $null -AuditDelegate $null
  -AuditAdmin $null on all mailboxes and let the default actions take over?
- If i want all the default actions + AuditOwner Copy, do i need to
  simply Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner @{Add="Copy"} for all mailboxes or do
  i need to explicitly add all actions that i want audited?
- For a mailbox with default actions currently set, eg. brand new
  mailbox, with tenant level auditing enabled, will Set-Mailbox
  -AuditOwner @{Add="Copy"} append to the list of actions or will it overwrite and treat this as the only action?

PS:  This could be the same as the question above, depending how you read/interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would say it all depends on your business need to enable/disable the audit log. Usually the logs are useful for security and troubleshooting.

And it could use “`Set-MailboxAuditBypassAssociation`” command to bypass the tenant level audit log configuration.

Next, in my testing, “`Set-OrganizationConfig AuditDisabled $true/$false`” is only to disable/enable tenant level audit log, it would not affect the existing actions. 
If you want to check the existing actions, you could use this command:

```
Get-Mailbox <identity of mailbox> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditOwner
```

If you want to add or remove some actions, you could use `Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner @{Add="xxx"}` or `Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner @{remove="xxx"}`.

If you use `Set-Mailbox -AuditOwner $null`, it will clean all the actions, not the default actions.

Just note: “`-AuditOwner xxx`” is to overwrite, and “`-AuditOwner @{Add="xxx"}`” is to add.

Please refer to the following article for default actions, I think you could first check the current actions and use add/remove to back to default actions.

And please note some actions can't be logged.

Here is a reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/enable-mailbox-auditing

Comment: Thank you Shaw.  With your comment regarding setting the actions to $null, if I was to set all mailbox auditing to $false and all actions to $null, would that “reset” all mailboxes to only get the default set of mailbox auditing on?

Comment: I think it would not. “$null” would clear all actions. For example, I assume “AuditOwner” default action is “UpdateFolderPermissions”, if you change to $null, it would also clear the default action, the action would be changed to none.

Comment: so how does one reset custom actions back to the default set?

Comment: In my understanding, I think it would manually use “@{add/remove="xxx"}” to change the actions. You could check the default actions in the above article.